# cracking sound sine tone in pyaudio

Tags: python, audio, alsa, pyaudio

I am using python and pyaudio to stream a pure sine tone using a callback method, in order to later modulate the sound via user input. Everything is fine except that when i run the code, i get 1-2 seconds of a cracking-buzzing sound associated to the warning message
ALSA lib pcm.c:7339:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
After that, the sine tone is streamed correctly. Any hints about how to remove the initial popping sound?
here is the code that stream the sound for one second

```
import pyaudio
import time
import numpy as np

CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100
freq = 600
CHUNK = 1024
lastchunk = 0
def sine(current_time):
    global freq,lastchunk
    length = CHUNK
    factor = float(freq)*2*np.pi/RATE
    this_chunk = np.arange(length)+lastchunk
    lastchunk = this_chunk[-1]
    return np.sin(this_chunk*factor)

def get_chunk(): 
    data  = sine(time.time())
    return data * 0.1


def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    chunk = get_chunk() * 0.25
    data = chunk.astype(np.float32).tostring()
    return (data, pyaudio.paContinue)

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32,
            channels=CHANNELS,
            rate=RATE,
            output=True,
            stream_callback=callback)

stream.start_stream()
time.sleep(1)   




stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
```

Cheers

Comment: Buffer underun generally means that your code (the callback) was unable to provide audio data in time for the next send to the DAC. Is there anything in your callback that would take longer to execute the first or first few times?

Comment: Looking again, what happens if you get rid of the `time.sleep(1)`? That could be making the program unresponsive for 1 second, preventing the callback from running and causing exactly the problem you've described.

Comment: well i need time.sleep(int) in order to indicate the length of the stream. Eliminating time.sleep results in a stream on 0 lengths as the stream is terminated right after by stream.stop_stream(). In fact changing the length of time.sleep() does not result in a different behaviour....

Comment: I realized that after looking at their docs and seeing that they actually use `time.sleep()`. Hopefully someone with experience in this particular library can come and give you and answer! Best of luck!

Comment: `current_time` is unused. Also, if you *would* need the time, you should use the `time_info` argument given to the callback function instead of `time.time()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PortAudio (the library behind PyAudio) allows you to specify a block size, which is typically called `CHUNK` in the PyAudio examples. If you don't specify one, the default is `0`, which in PortAudio terms means that the block size will be chosen automatically and will even change from callback to callback!

To check that, try printing `frame_count` (which is another name for the block size) within the callback. I suspect that PortAudio chooses a too small block size in the beginning and when that causes underruns, it increases the block size. Am I right?

To avoid this, you should specify a fixed block size from the beginning, using:

```
stream = p.open(..., frames_per_buffer=CHUNK, ...)
```

... where `frames_per_buffer` is yet another name for the block size.

This also makes more sense since up to now you use `length = CHUNK` in your code without knowing the actual block size!

If this still leads to underruns, you can try further increasing the block size to `2048`.

Finally, let me take the liberty to make a shameless plug for my own PortAudio wrapper, the [sounddevice](http://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/) module. It basically does the same as PyAudio, but it's easier to install, IMHO has a nicer API and it supports NumPy directly, without you having to do the manual conversions.

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved my problem! Actually, in order to make it work I had to apply BOTH of your suggestions, that is presetting the buffer length AND nincreasing its length to 2048.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer still didn't give perfect audio quality. Judging from what I heard (didn't measure) there are sometimes drop outs and/or phase jumps in the sine.  Based on the code in the PyAudio examples and what can be found [here](https://zach.se/generate-audio-with-python/) I came to this solution :

```
"""PyAudio Example: Play a wave file (callback version)."""

import pyaudio
import time
import math
from itertools import count
import numpy as np

RATE = 96000

# More efficient calculation but period = int(framer... causes high granularity for higher frequencies (15kHz becoming 16kHz for instance)
# def sine_wave(frequency=1000, framerate=RATE, amplitude=0.5):
#     period = int(framerate / frequency)
#     amplitude = max(min(amplitude, 1), 0)
#     lookup_table = [float(amplitude) * math.sin(2.0 * math.pi * float(frequency) *
#                                                 (float(i % period) / float(framerate))) for i in xrange(period)]
#     return (lookup_table[i % period] for i in count(0))

def sine_wave(frequency=440.0, framerate=RATE, amplitude=0.5):
    amplitude = max(min(amplitude, 1), 0)
    return (float(amplitude) * math.sin(2.0*math.pi*float(frequency)*(float(i)/float(framerate))) for i in count(0))

sine = [sine_wave(150), sine_wave(1500), sine_wave(15000)]

# instantiate PyAudio (1)
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

# define callback (2)
def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    wave = sine[0]
    data = [wave.next()]
    for i in range(frame_count - 1):
        data.append(wave.next())
    ret_array =np.array(data).astype(np.float32).tostring()
    return (ret_array, pyaudio.paContinue)

# open stream using callback (3)
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32,
                channels=1,
                rate=RATE,
                frames_per_buffer=1024,
                output=True,
                stream_callback=callback)

# start the stream (4)
stream.start_stream()

# Insert your own solution to end the sound
time.sleep(3)

# stop stream (6)
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()

# close PyAudio (7)
p.terminate()
```

This should be able to play the sine until your hardware dies or the next power outage... But I only tested for half an hour ;-)